# How to write query DISTINCT for 3 columns

Tags: mysql, sql

I would like to sum status for each unique set of rows by(client, prop1, prop2).
smth like : DISTINCT(client, prop1, prop2)

It's my table:

```
client  |  prop1  | prop2  | status
----------------------------------
name1   |  pr100  | pr310  | OK
name1   |  pr100  | pr310  | error
name1   |  pr100  | pr310  | OK
name1   |  pr100  | pr310  | OK
name2   |  pr255  | pr320  | OK
name2   |  pr255  | pr320  | OK
name2   |  pr255  | pr320  | error
name2   |  pr400  | pr320  | error
name3   |  pr400  | pr500  | OK
name3   |  pr400  | pr500  | OK
```

and i attempt to get this :

```
client  |  prop1  | prop2  | OK  | error
----------------------------------
name1   |  pr100  | pr310  | 3   |  1
name2   |  pr255  | pr320  | 2   |  1
name2   |  pr400  | pr320  | 0   |  1
name3   |  pr400  | pr500  | 2   |  0
```

Help please

Comment: Two prop columns *looks* like a design flaw.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is an aggregation, not a `select distinct`:

```
select client, prop1, prop2,
       sum(status = 'OK') as ok, sum(status = 'error') as error
from t
group by client, prop1, prop2;
```